# Convert XML string contains HTML entity

Tags: javascript, html, json, xml, encoding

I have following XML string and I need to extract values inside `<parameterizedString>` tag to an HTML table

```js
const strXML = '<steps id="0" last="4"><step id="1" type="ValidateStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Action Field 001&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Expected Result Field 001&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description/></step></steps>';

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(strXML, "application/xml");
console.log(doc.documentElement.textContent)
```

its throwing error error when I parse it,

Even tried to replace the string using following function, still failed.

```
function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
    var translate_re = /&(nbsp|amp|quot|lt|gt);/g;
    var translate = {
        "nbsp":" ",
        "amp" : "&",
        "quot": "\"",
        "lt"  : "<",
        "gt"  : ">"
    };
    return encodedString.replace(translate_re, function(match, entity) {
        return translate[entity];
    }).replace(/&#(\d+);/gi, function(match, numStr) {
        var num = parseInt(numStr, 10);
        return String.fromCharCode(num);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to extract the data from the <parameterizedString> tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to create a table the recommended way - the innerHTML statement could be safer if the textContent was sanitized first.

```js
const strXML = `<steps id="0" last="4"><step id="1" type="ValidateStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Action Field 001&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Expected Result Field 001&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description/></step><step id="2" type="RunStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Action Field 001&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Expected Result Field 001&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description/></step></steps>`;


const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(strXML, "application/xml");

const steps = [...doc.querySelectorAll('step')]

const table = document.createElement("table");
const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
steps.forEach(step => { console.log(step.querySelector("parameterizedString").textContent)
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  const cell1 = document.createElement("td");
  cell1.textContent = step.getAttribute("type");
  const cell2 = document.createElement("td");
  cell2.innerHTML = step.querySelector("parameterizedString").textContent;
  row.append(cell1)
  row.append(cell2)
  tbody.append(row)
})
table.append(tbody);
document.body.append(table);

// const fragment = document.createElement("div");
// fragment.innerHTML = doc.documentElement.textContent;
// console.log(fragment.innerHTML)
// document.body.append(fragment)
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; }
table div p { margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Comment: How to make in HTML table if we have multiple <steps><step id=1><step id=2><steps> ?

Comment: Great work, but i need this in pivote table format,

ValidateStep|RunStep
Action Field 001 |Action Field 001
Action Field 002 |Action Field 002

Comment: Ok, pay me. SO is not an elance website ;) You should be able to fix that yourself by changing my code

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, I got an another challenge, please check my new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77099992/extract-and-parse-xml-to-show-in-table-format-on-different-node-level?noredirect=1#comment135918982_77099992