# Extract and Parse XML to show in table format on different node level

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml

I have following XML format returning from API.

I need to extract in table format and re-parse back to same format.

**XML 1:**

```
<steps id="0" last="4">
    <step id="2" type="ValidateStep">
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 001</parameterizedString>
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 001</parameterizedString>
    </step>
    <compref id="4" ref="89">
        <step id="3" type="ValidateStep">
            <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 003</parameterizedString>
            <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 003</parameterizedString>
        </step>
    </compref>
</steps>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Array = [{step: 1, action:Stp 001, result:Act 001 },
         {step: 2, compref,        result:ref-89 },
         {step: 3, action:Stp 003, result:Act 003 }]
```

**XML 2:**

```
<steps id="0" last="6">
    <step id="2" type="ValidateStep">
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 001</parameterizedString>
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 001</parameterizedString>
    </step>
    <compref id="4" ref="89">
        <step id="3" type="ValidateStep">
            <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 003</parameterizedString>
            <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 003</parameterizedString>
        </step>
        <compref id="5" ref="91">
            <step id="6" type="ActionStep">
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 005</parameterizedString>
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 005</parameterizedString>
            </step>
        </compref>
    </compref>
</steps>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Array = [{step: 1, action:Stp 001, result:Act 001 },
         {step: 2, compref,        result:ref-89 },
         {step: 3, action:Stp 003, result:Act 003 },
         {step: 4, compref,        result:ref-91 },
         {step: 5, action:Stp 005, result:Act 005 }]
```

**XML 3:**

```
<steps id="0" last="9">
    <compref id="6" ref="90">
        <compref id="4" ref="89">
            <step id="7" type="ActionStep">
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 003</parameterizedString>
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 003</parameterizedString>
            </step>
            <compref id="8" ref="91">
                <step id="9" type="ActionStep">
                    <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 005</parameterizedString>
                    <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 005</parameterizedString>
                </step>
            </compref>
        </compref>
    </compref>
</steps>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Array = [{step: 1, compref,        result:ref-90 },
         {step: 2, compref,        result:ref-89 },
         {step: 3, action:Stp 003, result:Act 003 },
         {step: 4, compref,        result:ref-91 },
         {step: 5, action:Stp 005, result:Act 005 }]
```

**My Code**

```
const strXML = '**above XML string'
        const steps = [...strXML.querySelectorAll('step')];
        const stepData = new Array;
        steps.forEach((value, index) => {
            stepData.push({
                step: index + 1,
                action: value.querySelectorAll("parameterizedString")[0].textContent,
                result: value.querySelectorAll("parameterizedString")[1].textContent
            });
        });
```

The above code is just extracting steps tags also how can we extract `compref` ?

also above array needs to be converted back to XML format.

Comment: Output xpath is `//compref[@id="4"]/compref[@id="5"]`, is that correct?

Comment: it will differ we cannot relay on id, because in source system step can be moved to any row.

Comment: the question is if `compref` can be nested as shown.

Comment: Yes its correct. @LMC

Comment: I directly used
`let fullSteps='';
        this.data.forEach((value) => {
            fullSteps+='<step id="'+(value.step+1)+'" type="ValidateStep">'+
                            '<parameterizedString isformatted="true">'+encodeHTMLEntities(value.action)+'</parameterizedString>'+
                            '<parameterizedString isformatted="true">'+encodeHTMLEntities(value.result)+'</parameterizedString>'+
                        '</step>';
        });`
But i know it is not correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for? I'm not sure if this is the exact formatting you expected in the final XML string, but it should be close.

You can simply traverse the XML tags in order, and extract the contents of each element based on if it is a `compref` or `step` tag.

```js
const strXML = '<steps id="0" last="9"><compref id="6" ref="90"><compref id="4" ref="89"><step id="7" type="ActionStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 003</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 003</parameterizedString></step><compref id="8" ref="91"><step id="9" type="ActionStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 005</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 005</parameterizedString></step></compref></compref></compref></steps>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(strXML, "text/xml");
const nodes = [...xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("steps *")];
var stepData = new Array();
nodes.filter(function(value) {
   if (value.tagName == "compref") {
      stepData.push({
         step: stepData.length + 1,
         action: "compref",
         result: value.getAttribute("ref")
      });
   }
   else if (value.tagName == "step") {
      stepData.push({
         step: stepData.length + 1,
         action: value.querySelectorAll("parameterizedString")[0].textContent,
         result: value.querySelectorAll("parameterizedString")[1].textContent
      });
   }
});
console.log(stepData);
var xmlString = "<steps id='0' last='" + stepData.length + "'>";
stepData.filter(function(value) {
   xmlString += `<step id="${value.step}" type="ValidateStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true">${value.action}</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted="true">${value.result}</paramaterizedString></step>`;
});
xmlString += "</steps>";
var indentedXMLString = xmlString.replaceAll("<step ", "\n\t<step ").replaceAll("<parameterizedString", "\n\t\t<parameterizedString").replaceAll("</step>", "\n\t</step>").replace("</steps>", "\n</steps>");
console.log(indentedXMLString);
```

Comment: Let me try and get back on your code, Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: It doesn't worked for inner `compref`, Updated with XML 3 example. @Max Voisard

Comment: @Ragul See my edited answer where you can traverse the tags.